# Loop failing to terminate when conditions are met

Tags: python, loops

Why is the loop failing to terminate when meeting the required conditions.
I would appreciate an in-depth explanation rather than the code being corrected for me.

```
def get_name(name_type):
    return raw_input("Please enter you're {}name: \n".format(name_type)) 
def UserName():
    result = get_name("Fore"), get_name("Middle"), get_name("Sur")
    return " ".join(result)

print("You're UserName is : " + UserName())

while True:
    def Base():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n"))
    def Power():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n"))
    def result():
        return Base()*Power()

    print result()

    cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
    while cont.lower() not in ("yes","no"):
          cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
          if cont=="no":
              break
```

Comment: Because you're not breaking when `cont=="yes"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it does:

```
def get_name(name_type):
    return raw_input("Please enter you're {}name: \n".format(name_type)) 
def UserName():
    result = get_name("Fore"), get_name("Middle"), get_name("Sur")
    return " ".join(result)

print("You're UserName is : " + UserName())
print

cont = 'no'

while cont != 'yes':
    def Base():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n"))
    def Power():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n"))
    def result():
        return Base()*Power()

    print result()

    cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
    while cont.lower() not in ("yes","no"):
          cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
          if cont=="yes":
              break
```

Comment: I suppose you should rename your var "cont" to "discont".

Comment: I think OP needs to break out of the outer `while True` loop, which this code does not accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` statement is nested within the inner `while` loop, so it is breaking that loop rather than the `while True` loop.  I think moving the conditional statement out of the inner loop and changing the logic to `if discont=='yes'` (note:  renamed var to more accurate description) will give you what you want:

```
while True:

    ...

    discont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ").lower()
    while discont not in ("yes","no"):
        discont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ").lower()
    if discont=="yes":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inside two while loops. <s>You want to break out of both if the user wants to exit, otherwise only out of the inner one:</s> Move the condition out of the while loop, then it should work:

```
from sys import exit

...

while True:
    def Base():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n"))
    def Power():
        return int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n"))
    def result():
        return Base()*Power()

    print result()

    cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
    while cont.lower() not in ("yes","no"):
        cont = raw_input("Would you like to quit? yes/no > ")
    if cont=="yes":
        break
```

The next piece of advice has nothing to do with your question, but I'll give it anyways: There's no need to define the `Base`, `Power`, and `Result` functions in every loop iteration. Just assign the values to variables and print directly:

```
base = int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n"))
power = int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n"))
print base*power
```

Comment: thanks for the advice L3viathan and i completely agree, however for the purpose of my assignment i have to use functions consisiting of only one command each. anoying i know and rather pointless but there you go.

Comment: @DarrenMacis Then you can still define the functions outside the loop. Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: What if he wants to do something after the `while True` loop?

Comment: @Billy I assumed they didn't based on "Would you like to quit?", but you're right, and your answer is better.

Comment: i like this answer, it has helped me understand why my problem is occuring. however i stiil havents solved it yet lol, so im going to go get some food and come back to it in a bit.